# Dictionary(words such as names, items, etc) library for .NET?

Tags: .net, random

I am looking for a library that can be used in .NET to retrieve strings of random names(John, Peter), items(table, bottle), objects etc

I want to use this in a database-filling operation and the requirement is that the data should look real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, maybe try using one of the sample databases such as AdventureWorks, e.g.

```
select top 10 FirstName, LastName
from AdventureWorks.Person.Contact order by newid()
```

Comment: i liked your approach and yes, i have access to the sql server

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a .NET library, but you could try Red Gate's [SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm) tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is specific enough so it's obvious that there is no built-in library to do the job. You could however download lists of names(first/last) from the internet and feed it to your database.

One such names list can be found [here](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/). Additionally, sites like [Namepedia](http://www.namepedia.org/en/firstname/) and [Randomnames.com](http://www.randomnames.com/allnames.asp?g=m) may prove helpful.